# Dynamically added table rows not deleting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have some javascript/jquery written to dynamically add and remove table rows from a fieldset. My function works just fine for pre-existing table rows (they can be removed properly). However, after adding a new table row I cannot delete the new item until I delete a pre-existing row. I'm guessing this has something to do with how event binding works in javascript/jquery (i.e. the click function is not bound to the new elements until an event is fired and the bind is rerun). However, I haven't been able to find any resources regarding this issue in my extensive searching and thus have no idea how to fix it.

Please see the following jsfiddle (press the '+' to add a new table row and '-' to delete it):

https://jsfiddle.net/znwL8x0j/

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset class="dedupe-rate">
    <legend>Workloads</legend>
    <table id="workloads">
        <tr>
            <th>
                +/-
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Type
            </th>
            <th>
                %
            </th>
            <th>
                Ratio
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="workload-1">
            <td class="remove-workload">
                -
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="workload-name" id="name-w1" name="name-w1" value="Virtual Desktop" size="20">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-type" id="type-w1" name="type-w1">
                    <option value="VDI" selected>VDI</option>
                    <option value="VSI">VSI</option>
                    <option value="Email">Email</option>
                    <option value="Analytics">Analytics</option>
                    <option value="OLTP">OLTP</option>
                    <option value="DW">DW</option>
                    <option value="Compression">Compression</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="workload-percent" id="percent-w1" name="percent-w1" value="25" size="1">%
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-ratio" id="ratio-w1" name="ratio-w1">
                    <option value="7">7:1</option>
                    <option value="8">8:1</option>
                    <option value="9">9:1</option>
                    <option value="10" selected>10:1</option>
                    <option value="11">11:1</option>
                    <option value="12">12:1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="workload-2">
            <td class="remove-workload">
                -
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="workload-name" id="name-w2" name="name-w2" value="Virtual Server" size="20">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-type" id="type-w2" name="type-w2">
                    <option value="VDI">VDI</option>
                    <option value="VSI" selected>VSI</option>
                    <option value="Email">Email</option>
                    <option value="Analytics">Analytics</option>
                    <option value="OLTP">OLTP</option>
                    <option value="DW">DW</option>
                    <option value="Compression">Compression</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="percent-w2" class="workload-percent" id="percent-w2" value="15" size="1">%
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-ratio" id="ratio-w2" name="ratio-w2">
                    <option value="5">5:1</option>
                    <option value="6">6:1</option>
                    <option value="7" selected>7:1</option>
                    <option value="8">8:1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="workload-3">
            <td class="remove-workload">
                -
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="workload-name" id="name-w3" name="name-w3" value="Email" size="20">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-type" id="type-w3" name="type-w3">
                    <option value="VDI">VDI</option>
                    <option value="VSI">VSI</option>
                    <option value="Email" selected>Email</option>
                    <option value="Analytics">Analytics</option>
                    <option value="OLTP">OLTP</option>
                    <option value="DW">DW</option>
                    <option value="Compression">Compression</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="percent-w3" class="workload-percent" id="percent-w3" value="15" size="1">%
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-ratio" id="ratio-w3" name="ratio-w3">
                    <option value="4">4:1</option>
                    <option value="5" selected>5:1</option>
                    <option value="6">6:1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="workload-4">
            <td class="remove-workload">
                -
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="workload-name" id="name-w4" name="name-w4" value="Analytics" size="20">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-type" id="type-w4" name="type-w4">
                    <option value="VDI">VDI</option>
                    <option value="VSI">VSI</option>
                    <option value="Email">Email</option>
                    <option value="Analytics" selected>Analytics</option>
                    <option value="OLTP">OLTP</option>
                    <option value="DW">DW</option>
                    <option value="Compression">Compression</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="percent-w4" class="workload-percent" id="percent-w4" value="15" size="1">%
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-ratio" id="ratio-w4" name="ratio-w4">
                    <option value="3">3:1</option>
                    <option value="4" selected>4:1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="workload-5">
            <td class="remove-workload">
                -
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="workload-name" id="name-w5" name="name-w5" value="Online Transaction Processing" size="20">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-type" id="type-w5" name="type-w5">
                    <option value="VDI">VDI</option>
                    <option value="VSI">VSI</option>
                    <option value="Email">Email</option>
                    <option value="Analytics">Analytics</option>
                    <option value="OLTP" selected>OLTP</option>
                    <option value="DW">DW</option>
                    <option value="Compression">Compression</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="percent-w5" class="workload-percent" id="percent-w5" value="10" size="1">%
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-ratio" id="ratio-w5" name="ratio-w5">
                    <option value="3">3:1</option>
                    <option value="4" selected>4:1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="workload-6">
            <td class="remove-workload">
                -
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="workload-name" id="name-w6" name="name-w6" value="Data Warehousing" size="20">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-type" id="type-w6" name="type-w6">
                    <option value="VDI">VDI</option>
                    <option value="VSI">VSI</option>
                    <option value="Email">Email</option>
                    <option value="Analytics">Analytics</option>
                    <option value="OLTP">OLTP</option>
                    <option value="DW" selected>DW</option>
                    <option value="Compression">Compression</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="percent-w6" class="workload-percent" id="percent-w6" value="10" size="1">%
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-ratio" id="ratio-w6" name="ratio-w6">
                    <option value="2">2:1</option>
                    <option value="3" selected>3:1</option>
                    <option value="4">4:1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="workload-7">
            <td class="remove-workload">
                -
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="workload-name" id="name-w7" name="name-w7" value="Media Compression" size="20">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-type" id="type-w7" name="type-w7">
                    <option value="VDI">VDI</option>
                    <option value="VSI">VSI</option>
                    <option value="Email">Email</option>
                    <option value="Analytics">Analytics</option>
                    <option value="OLTP">OLTP</option>
                    <option value="DW">DW</option>
                    <option value="Compression" selected>Compression</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="percent-w7" class="workload-percent" id="percent-w7" value="5" size="1">%
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-ratio" id="ratio-w7" class="ratio-w7">
                    <option value="1.2">1.2:1</option>
                    <option value="1.3">1.3:1</option>
                    <option value="1.4" selected>1.4:1</option>
                    <option value="1.5">1.5:1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="workload-8">
            <td class="remove-workload">
                -
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="workload-name" id="name-w8" name="name-w8" value="Other" size="20">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="workload-type" id="type-w8" name="type-w8">
                    <option value="VDI">VDI</option>
                    <option value="VSI">VSI</option>
                    <option value="Email">Email</option>
                    <option value="Analytics">Analytics</option>
                    <option value="OLTP">OLTP</option>
                    <option value="DW">DW</option>
                    <option value="Compression">Compression</option>
                    <option value="Other" selected>Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="percent-w8" class="workload-percent" id="percent-w8" value="5" size="1">%
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="workload-ratio" id="ratio-w8" name="ratio-w8" value="3" size="1" style="text-align: right">:1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="add-workload">
            <td class="add-workload">
                +
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="totals">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                Total:
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id="total-percent"></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id="average-ratio"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

**CSS**

```
fieldset {
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

.dedupe-rate {
    width: 440px;
}

.add-workload, .remove-workload {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #A8A8A8;
}

.add-workload:hover, .remove-workload:hover {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 800;
    background-color: #A8A8A8;
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
function workload_totals_update(toUpdate) {
    var totalPercent = 0;
    $(".workload-percent").each(function() {
        totalPercent += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    var averageRatio = 0;
    $(".workload-ratio").each(function() {
        averageRatio += parseInt($(this).val())*$(this).closest("tr").find(".workload-percent").val()*0.01;
    });


    $("#total-percent").text(totalPercent.toString() + "%");
    if (totalPercent == 100) {
        $("#total-percent").css("color", "#00AA00");
    }
    else {
        $("#total-percent").css("color", "#FF0000");
    }
    $("#average-ratio").text(averageRatio.toFixed(2) + ":1");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    workload_totals_update();

    $(".workload-ratio").bind("change", function(){workload_totals_update()});
    $(".workload-ratio").bind("keyup", function(){workload_totals_update()});
    $(".workload-percent").bind("keyup", function(){workload_totals_update()});
    //Add/Remove Workloads
    $(".remove-workload").click(function() {
        var currRow = $(this).closest("tr");
        var nextRow = $(this).closest("tr").next("tr");

        while (nextRow.attr("id") != "add-workload") {

            var prevName = currRow.find(".workload-name");
            var nextName = nextRow.find(".workload-name");
            prevName.attr("id", nextName.attr("id"));
            prevName.attr("name", nextName.attr("name"));
            prevName.val(nextName.val());

            var prevType = currRow.find(".workload-type");
            var nextType = nextRow.find(".workload-type");
            prevType.attr("id", nextType.attr("id"));
            prevType.attr("name", nextType.attr("name"));
            prevType.val(nextType.val());

            var prevPercent = currRow.find(".workload-percent");
            var nextPercent = nextRow.find(".workload-percent");
            prevPercent.attr("id", nextPercent.attr("id"));
            prevPercent.attr("name", nextPercent.attr("name"));
            prevPercent.val(nextPercent.val());

            var prevRatio = currRow.find(".workload-ratio");
            var nextRatio = nextRow.find(".workload-ratio");
            prevRatio.attr("id", nextRatio.attr("id"));
            prevRatio.attr("name", nextRatio.attr("name"));
            prevRatio.val(nextRatio.val());

            currRow = nextRow;
            nextRow = nextRow.next("tr");
        }

        currRow.remove();

    });

    $(".add-workload").click(function() {
        var workloadCount = $("#workloads tr").length - 7;
        var workloadNum = "w" + (workloadCount + 1).toString();
        var trId = "workload-" + (workloadCount+1).toString();
        var name = "name-" + workloadNum;
        var type = "type-" + workloadNum;
        var percent = "percent-" + workloadNum;
        var ratio = "ratio-" + workloadNum;

        var removeWorkload = '<td class="remove-workload">-</td>'
        var workloadName = '<td><input type="text" class="workload-name" id="'+name+'" name="'+name+'" value="Other" size="20"></td>';
        var workloadType = '<td><select class="workload-type" id="'+type+'" name="'+type+'"><option value="VDI">VDI</option><option value="VSI">VSI</option><option value="Email">Email</option><option value="Analytics">Analytics</option><option value="OLTP">OLTP</option><option value="DW">DW</option><option value="Compression">Compression</option><option value="Other" selected>Other</option></select>';
        var workloadPercent = '<td><input type="text" name="'+percent+'" class="workload-percent" id="'+percent+'" value="0" size="1">%</td>';
        var workloadRatio = '<td><input type="text" class="workload-ratio" id="'+ratio+'" name="'+ratio+'" value="3" size="1" style="text-align: right">:1</td>';

        $(this).closest("tr").prev("tr").after('<tr id="' + trId + '">' + removeWorkload + workloadName + workloadType + workloadPercent + workloadRatio + '</tr>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you have a while loop at checks for `while (nextRow.attr("id") != "add-workload") {`. This seems like it would stop new rows at the bottom of the page from deleting as the next row is the add-workload row.

Comment: Dynamically added elements do not magically get event handlers that were attached before they were created. Just like you you do not hear your name called when you are not in the same room. You need to rebind the events or learn about event delegation.

Comment: @epascarello that is what I figured, I'm just not entirely sure how to rebind the event handler to the new elements

Comment: @BrantOlsen It has no problem deleting the last row because it just skips the while loop (which handles moving tag numbers up so they're still sequential) and just deletes the current row (which sits outside the while loop) `currRow.remove();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi brother try to change :

```
$(".remove-workload").click(function() {
```

By :

```
$('body').on('click',".remove-workload",function() {
```

That should work.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Could you please explain why it works? I would really like to know the underlying reasons here.

Comment: You are welcome, using the **.on()** method you can work with the both current and FUTURE elements (like a new element created by a script), not **.click()** method that not work if the DOM is changed after loading of page.